# How to generate a security token for an iframe?

Tags: security, iframe, drupal-7

So, I have to generate an iframe from a Drupal 7 view (custom content blog) to be embedded in a site with authentication. Generating the iframe is less of an issue than how to generate a cross domain security token. I have no idea how to approach this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: um, so what would be the requirements for this token?

Comment: it's supposed to be "long"